# Gravitomagnetic railgun

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, gravity, acceleration, electric-current

Would a [gravitomagnetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitoelectromagnetism) analogue of a [railgun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Railgun) work as expected, in theory?

[image]

Consider replacing the electric currents on each rail with mass currents. Then place a mass between the rails, moving with constant velocity toward one of them, as shown by the red arrow in the diagram. Would the mass be accelerated in the direction parallel to the rails, as indicated by the green arrow?

Comment: Mass current density or mass flux (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitoelectromagnetism#Equations).

Comment: The gravitional force is extremely weak compared to the electrical and magnetic forces.  How would you achieve a mass current density of sufficient strength to launch anything?

Comment: The force you see in the diagram is created by the Lorenz Force due to the current flow through an armature. I don't know that there's a force that is exerted on mass currents.

Comment: There is an analogue of the Lorentz force for gravitation, I believe, shown on the page I linked to. It arises for essentially the same reason as electromagnetism: Lorentz contraction.

Comment: I believe each mass current must be changing and not static in order to generate any GEM forces.

Comment: @RossPresser Constant electric current generates a constant magnetic field. Likewise, constant mass current generates a constant gravitomagnetic field.

Comment: @user76284 You might be right; I'm not enough of an expert. Have you seen Forward's ["Guidelines to Antigravity"](https://idoc.pub/documents/robert-lforward-guidelines-to-antigravity-19n09zgmz2nv)? He describes three separate effects in some detail.

Comment: @user76284 A constant magnetic field will not make a charged particle go faster; it will make it go in a circle. That's why I think a changing mass current is required.

Comment: @RossPresser Thanks for the link. Forward's work is actually what inspired my question.

Comment: @RossPresser Unlike a free particle, the railgun constrains the mass current between the rails to always have a positive component in the I direction. Meanwhile, the magnetic field is constant in the B direction. Thus the mass current should always experience a force with a positive component in the F direction.

Comment: Ok, butting out now :)